# Make select() crack without writing to a file desc?

Tags: c, select, timeout

I have this thread in my application that monitors a set of client sockets. I use `select()` to block until a client makes a request, so that I can handle it efficiently without multiplying threads.

Now, problem is, when I add a new client to the list of clients, I have to wait for the timeout of `select()` (set to 10 seconds) to actually add the new socket to the listened sockets.

So I'd like to make `select()` crack *before* the timeout so that a client can be listened to immediately.

I already have a solution to that: create a dummy socketpair that I always include in my listened sockets list, and in which I write to make `select()` crack, but I'm hoping there's a better solution out there.

**Edit**:
I have no access to `eventfd()` because the GLibc I use is too old (and I have no mean to update it). So I might have to use a fifo or a socket.

Do you know any?

Thanks!

Comment: You could kill the thread using `pthread_kill` or similar and then restart it...

Comment: Well that would be... overkill wouldn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way of waking up a select loop is to add the read end of a [`pipe()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html) fd pair to the select's watching set. When you need to wake up the select loop, write some dummy data to the write end of the file descriptor.

Note that on linux you might also want to consider using an [`eventfd()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) instead of a [`pipe()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html) - it may be somewhat more efficient (although less portable).

You could also handle the listen socket in the select loop instead of handing it off to another thread - this would wake up the select loop implicitly when a new client comes.

Comment: `eventfd()` is exactly what I needed! Since I'm focusing on linux, it's perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Okay update on this: I don't have the last GLibc available to support eventfd(), so I have to fall back using fifo or a socket. 
What's not cool with fifo is all that open()/close() and filesystem thing that I'd like to prevent. Is there a quick way to prevent that?

Comment: Did you read the `fifo()` manpage? There's no filesystem access involved - it just gives you a pair of file descriptors ready to go. The one thing to be careful of is that you use `fcntl()` to set `FD_CLOEXEC` if you're going to be exec-ing other programs.

Comment: Yes I did, the thing is that a fifo it stays on filesystem on program crash or reboot, so I'd rather use `socketpair()` to generate two unnamed connected sockets that I set as non-blocking.  
That way I get them without a file path and I can use just like a fifo, with the advantage of not having to take care of the cleanup.  
Do you see any problem with that?

Comment: crap, mixed up my syscalls - meant pipe()!

Comment: Also, `socketpair()` is fine, but `pipe()` may be somewhat lower overhead, possibly; it's one-way and missing some of the more advanced features of `AF_UNIX` sockets like `SCM_RIGHTS` transfers

Comment: Well I implemented the `socketpair()` thing, but `pipe()` is totally the same and probably less overhead yeah. If performance becomes the bottleneck I'll see what pipes give :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same `select()` call to wait for the incoming connection by including the listener socket in the FD set; this way, when it indicates that a connection is waiting, you can accept the connection without blocking and add the new file descriptor to the set.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought at first, but the thing is, my main listening socket is already used on another select() in a different part of the application (the listening socket can be used for other things than adding clients), so your solution is impractical in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can raise signal to force EINTR from select(), but signal processing in multithreaded programs is black magic and socketpair() is simpler and more reliable.

Comment: Signals in a multi-threaded program just to wake up a select loop? Way more complex than it needs to be... hell, people use the fifo-wakeup-pattern from signal handlers precisely to _avoid_ dealing with signals. Don't do it in reverse.

Comment: This is exactly what I was saying: you can but you should not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WSAEventSelect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to link a windows socket with HEVENT and wait then linked to socket HEVENT with another descriptors using [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).